# Что такое "раж"?

Tags: этимология

"Войти в раж" говорят, подразумевая, что человек вошел в состояние азарта, сильно увлекся чем-то. А что такое изначально "раж" и почему в него входят?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

как преподаватель ин. яз,  в том числе французского, могу подтвердить значение слова "rage" - ярость; азарт; страстное желание; неудержимое стремление. В русском:  войти в раж = войти в азарт ( мое личное понимание этого выражения)   Оrage, ouragan - буря, ураган.   К тому же, слово ураган, раж  перешли  в русский почти без изменения в произношении.( ураган - во франц. лишь носовой звук в конце слова). В русском есть и однокоренные слова:  кураж -courage ( фр.)  - мужество, смелость, храбрость. И в русском образовался даже глагол "куражиться "- издеваться над кем либо, выставляя себя "сверхчеловеком" ( личное толкование- ощущение этого выражения). думаю, что  и такие слова, как враг - вражда - враждовать и т.п. являются однокоренными

Answer (score 2):

Этимологический словарь Крылова говорит: "Это слово, имеющее значение "ярость, волнение", было заимствовано из французского, где rage – "бешенство" образовано от rager – "злиться". Отметим и восходящее к той же основе английское rage." Так что , входя в раж, мы входим в исступление.

Comment: >Этимологический словарь Крылова
>**ВРАГ**
>Заимствование из старославянского, восходит к общеславянской основе vorgt, родственного древненемецкому **wargs – "злой"** и готскому wrikan – "преследовать".  

Нельзя ли считать родственным такое совпадение? *Враг, вражда, вражий, вражба*. Враги злятся, входят в исступление и в раж.

Comment: Почему  нельзя,  можно,  особенно  в  полёте  воображения.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Ушакова: "РАЖ, ража, мн. нет, муж. (франц. rage) (разг.). Ярость, неистовство, исступление, сильное волнение".
http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?stype=undefined&SWord=%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%96

Answer (score 0):

Словарь Церк.-слав. языка Г.Дьяченко http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0536.htm даёт такие статьи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раж (как состояние пограничное) опасен и превращает человека во врага себе самому, исключает разумность поступков. Лезть на рожон — в этом смысле — идти на большой риск.